# ConstraintLayout view with width of 0dp disappears

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to learn constraint layout by converting a list item from a linear + relative layout. I have a checkbox and 3 text views arranged in a line followed by a recyclerview underneath.

Phone preview:

[image: Phone preview]

Tablet preview:

[image: Tablet preview]

Code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/line_item_qty"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/line_item_qty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/line_item_name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox"
        tools:text="5 x" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/line_item_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/line_item_price"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/line_item_qty"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Club sandwich with ranch dressing and extra mustard" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/line_item_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/line_item_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:text="€4.50" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/item_mods_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/line_item_name"
        tools:itemCount="3"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_line_modifier"
        tools:orientation="vertical" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see the preview renders fine but when I run the code, the name of the item is gone (it's width needs to be 0dp, if it's wrap_content then on phones it just previews as one line of text and overlaps the qty and price text views).

Image from device (tablet):
[image: Image from device]

Is it because I am aligning baselines to the name and the name itself has no bottom constraint?

Comment: Try adding ending constraint to `line_item_qty` and starting constraint to `line_item_price`?

Also, to avoid `it's width needs to be 0dp, if it's wrap_content then on phones it just previews as one line of text and overlaps the qty and price text views`, you can try adding `constrainedWidth=true` to the name TextView.

Comment: Thanks Nguyễn I tried that, constraining the views on either side to the name appears to make no difference, design editor doesn't allow it so I'm not sure it's valid to have them all constraining off of each other but the IDE doesn't complain. I think there is something to the wrap_content and the `layout_constrainedWidth` field, with it set to true it almost works (preview looks fine but the device image looks like this https://imgur.com/uCHledm). I can't explain why the price is not anchored to the end (parent widths are all match_parent and the price is only end constrained to the parent)

Comment: FYI I copy your code in the question, replace `tools:text` with `android:text` and it just work well. If I replace the value of `line_item_name` with empty string or short string, the price is right-aligned as well.

How about commenting out your code that update the UI, and verify the layout using hard-coded value first?

My device is Pixel 4 Android 12S beta.

Comment: Ah ok thank you yes after investigating further I can see it's an issue with the inflation of the list items and there appears to be nothing wrong with the constraints. I was inflating the view with the LayoutInflater that doesn't take a parent. And it seems to break the name only. If you want to add that as an answer you can, basically this `ItemLineItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context))` became this `ItemLineItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)`

Comment: I see. It's good it works for you at lest. I'm fine keeping the comments :D. It was not a big trouble after all IMO.

Comment: Make sure your RecyclreView is `setHasFixedSize(false)`

Answer (score 0):

Add `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="line_item_name"` to your `line_item_price`, so your price will be always come after your item name

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/line_item_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/line_item_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="line_item_name" //Add this
        tools:text="€4.50" />
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that had no effect. I also tried constraining the end of `line_item_qty` to the start of the name, so either side has a constraint both ways. Interestingly the design editor does not let you do these two constraints when baseline constraints are used, and you have to do it by code.

Answer (score 0):

It's good that you are learning new things and trying to implement them.
Below is the code that will give you your desired output.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/line_item_qty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/checkBox"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBox"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="5 x" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/line_item_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/line_item_price"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/line_item_qty"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/line_item_qty"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/line_item_qty"
            tools:text="Club sandwich with ranch dressing and extra mustard" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/line_item_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/line_item_name"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/line_item_name"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            tools:text="€4.50" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/item_mods_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBox"
            tools:itemCount="3"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_line_modifier"
            tools:orientation="vertical" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Do let me know if you have any queries on this.

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mehul, I wanted to use baseline constraints as Sean McQuillan recommends that here (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9Zstbk0lPw&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc8WFYCR9esqGGY0vOZm2l6e). I will update the question to note that. However your solution seems to have the same effect when running the code, i.e. name is gone (but preview is fine). Perhaps there is something wrong with the device I'll keep experimenting. Also in the preview your solution expands the name both up and down when it's multiple lines on a phone., and because it's a list it should only expand downwards (https://imgur.com/LoKMEup)